# What are the getter and setter methods?

Tags: methods, getter, setter

**I would like to know about the getter method and the setter method as well as the function that each one occupies**

Answer (score 0):

Reading Javatpoint,

> Getter and setter methods are frequently used in Java programming.
> Getter and setter methods in Java are widely used to access and
> manipulate the values of class fields. Usually, class fields are
> decorated with a private access specifier. Thus, to access them,
> public access specifiers are used with the getter and setter methods.
> https://www.javatpoint.com/getter-and-setter-method-in-java-example